# Overwrite volume contents with container's contents

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-volume, docker-container

I have a volume which contains data that needs to stay persisted. When creating the volume for the first time, and mounting it to my node container, all container contents are copied to the volume, and everything behaves as expected. The issue is that when I change a few files in my node container, I remove the old image and container, and rebuild them from scratch. When running the updated container, the container's files don't get copied into the volume. This means that the volume still contains the old files, and therefore when the volume is mounted in the container, no updated functionality is present, and I have to remove and recreate the volume from scratch, which I can't do since the volume's data needs to be persisted.

Here is my dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0
COPY CommandLineTool App/CommandLineTool/ 
COPY NeedBackupNodeServer App/NeedBackupNodeServer/
WORKDIR /App/NeedBackupNodeServer
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | bash - \ 
    && apt update \
    && apt install -y nodejs
EXPOSE 5001
ENTRYPOINT ["node", "--trace-warnings", "index.js"]
```

Here are my commands and expected output

```
docker volume create nodeServer-and-commandLineTool-volume 

docker build -t need-backup-image -f Dockerfile . 

docker run -p 5001:5001 --name need-backup-container -v nodeServer-and-commandLineTool-volume:/App need-backup-image -a
```

when running

```
docker exec need-backup-container cat index.js
```

the file is present and contains the latest updates, since the volume was just created.

Now when I update some files, I need to rebuild the image and the container, so I run

```
docker rm need-backup-container   

docker rmi need-backup-image  

docker build -t need-backup-image -f Dockerfile . 

docker run -p 5001:5001 --name need-backup-container -v nodeServer-and-commandLineTool-volume:/App need-backup-image -a
```

Now I thought that when running

```
docker exec need-backup-container cat index.js
```

I'd see the updated file changes, but nope, I only see the old files that were first created when the volume was mounted for the first time.
So my question is, is there anyway to achieve overwriting the volume's files when creating a container?

Comment: Can you put your data and your source code in different directories?  Then you can mount a persistent volume on `/data` and it won't overwrite the image code in `/app`.  You usually shouldn't keep your application or library dependencies in volumes for exactly the lifecycle reasons you describe here (and also because the "copy files into the volume" doesn't work for things that aren't specifically Docker named volumes).

Comment: @DavidMaze So I create a volume /data which contains all the data, but then the /app needs to access this /data as well, since the server needs to have access to those files. The problem still remains though, because when rebuilding the image and mounting the /app volume to the container, the changed files will still not be updated, since it seems the problem still remains, that I can't overwrite the volume files with the container's files

Comment: Correct, `/app` needs to read from `/data`.  (Or it could be a subdirectory `/app/data` and that's fine, just anywhere that is different from the directory that has the application proper.)  You do not mount a volume over `/app`, only the data directory.

Comment: @DavidMaze Well, that worked like a charm. Would u mind adding this as an answer so I can accept it and others would find the answer if they faced such a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your application needs persistent data, it should be stored in a different directory from the application code.  This can be in a dedicated `/data` directory or in a subdirectory of your application; the important thing is that, when you mount a volume to hold the persistent data, it does not hide your application code.

In a Node application, for example, you could refer to a `./data` for your data files:

```js
import { open } from 'fs/promises';
import { join } from 'path';
const dataDir = process.env.DATA_DIR || 'data';
const fh = await open(join(dataDir, 'file.txt'), 'rw');
```

Then in your Dockerfile you'd need to create that directory.  If you set up a non-root user, that directory, but not your code, should be owned by the user.

```sh
FROM node:lts

# Create the non-root user
RUN adduser --system --no-create-home nonroot

# Install the Node application normally
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json .
RUN npm ci
COPY index.js .

# Create the data directory
RUN mkdir data && chown nonroot data

# Specify how to run the container
USER nonroot
CMD ["node", "index.js"]
```

Then when you launch the container, mount the volume *only* on the data directory, not over the entire `/app` tree.

```sh
docker run \
  -p 5001:5001 \
  --name need-backup-container \
  -v nodeServer-and-commandLineTool-volume:/app/data \
  need-backup-image
#                                          ^^^^^^^^^
```

Note that the Dockerfile as shown here would also let you use a host directory instead of a Docker named volume, and specify the host uid when you run the container.  You do not need to make any changes to the image to do this.

```sh
docker run \
  -p 5002:5001 \
  --name same-image-with-bind-mount \
  -u $(id -u) \
  -v "$PWD/app-data:/app/data" \
  need-backup-image
```